# Input para un snake en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

lo que quiero es crear un snake y me gustaría poder detectar que teclas pulsa el usuario. Tengo una versión hecha en C++ en la que las teclas pulsadas las detecta un bucle que está en otro thread como muestro aquí:

```
vec2 dir(0,0);

int main()
{
    thread Input(input);
    // Más codigo que mueve la serpiente
}

void input()
{
    while (true)
    {
        char letra = _getch();
        switch (letra)
        {
        case 's':
            dir.x = 0; dir.y = 1; break;
        case 'w':
            dir.x = 0; dir.y = -1; break;
        case 'a':
            dir.x = -1; dir.y = 0; break;
        case 'd':
            dir.x = 1; dir.y = 0; break;
        case 27:
            dir.x = -2; break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Me pregunto si hay alguna manera de conseguir el mismo resultado en python (estoy empezando y no sé mucho). He probado con el modulo "import threading" y un código identico que el de C++ pero aun así el programa se queda esperando al input en vez actuar de fondo. Estoy haciendo algo mal o simplemente no se puede. Este es el código que tengo:

```
import os
import random
import threading
import msvcrt as m

def clean():
    os.system("cls")

class vec2:
    // Una clase para controlar la posición


class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name

   def run(self):
      input()


class parte:
    // Una clase con la información de las partes de la serpiente


dir = vec2()



serpiente = [parte(vec2(), "O")]

comida = parte(vec2(random.randint(0, 20), random.randint(0, 20)), "+")

print(comida.pos)

thread = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread.start()
thread.run()

while dir != vec2(-1, -1):
    // Muevo la serpiente

thread.join()


def imput():
    while True:
        x = m.getch()

        if x == "w":
            dir = vec2(1, 0)
        elif x == "s":
            dir = vec2(-1, 0)
        elif x == "a":
            dir = vec2(0, -1)
        elif x == "d":
            dir = vec2(0, 1)
        elif x == "x":
            dir = vec2(-1, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la función `input()` es bloqueante, lo que necesitas es una rutina no bloqueante. En windows puedes hacer uso de el módulo `msvcrt` y las funciones [`msvcrt.kbhit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) para saber si hay pendiente alguna tecla en la cola y [`msvcrt.getch()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) para leerla

```
import msvcrt
import time

ch = b""

while True:

    ts = time.time()
    print("{0} {1} (use `q` para salir)".format(ts, "ultima tecla presionada {0}".format(ch.decode()) if ch != b"" else ""))

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
        if ch == b"q":
          break
```